# Installing medibuntu fails

Tags: 11.10, medibuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

I'm trying to install Medibuntu following the instructions from [Medibuntu site](http://medibuntu.org/repository.php), I paste in the terminal:

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

it fails with:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 61260473F9D8BC54
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using one of the following PPAs without their signing key:

https://launchpad.net/~shiki/+archive/mediainfo

https://launchpad.net/~shiki/+archive/personal

If you remember to have added one (or more) of these PPAs, you can import the key with this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9D8BC54
```

Then, you can proceed adding the Medibuntu archive again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the KEYNUMBER with the actual keynumber that you should now have from running apt-get again.Type

gpg --keyserver wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net --recv-keys KEYNUMBER
gpg --armor --export KEYNUMBER | sudo apt-key add -

Update apt-get.Type

sudo apt-get update

That is it. If GPG error is still there, simply type the following commands, taking care to replace the number of the key that displayed in the error message:

gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  61260473F9D8BC54

gpg -a --export 61260473F9D8BC54 | sudo apt-key add -